Is there a way to assign a pattern to java LocalDateTime like it's being done with DateTimeFormatter?
I have this field for appointment time which is of type LocalDateTime. I want to format it so that it can only accept hour and minute instead of the whole year,month,day, hour,minute etc that it normally returns. I know that I can achieve that by passing a string and a time formatter but I just want to pass the pattern directly to it
    public class BookingDto {
        private Long doctorId;
        private Long patientId;
        private LocalDate appointmentDate;
    
         //This is the attribute
         // I need it in this format 08:23
        private LocalDateTime appointmentTime;
        private BigDecimal totalPrice;
        private Status status;
        private String note;
    }


Are you looking for LocalTime?

I’d use a LocalDateTime for both appointment date and time. You can build one from yourLocalDate.atTime(yourLocalTime). And retrieve date and time individually: yourLocalDateTime.toLocalDate() gives you the date, and similarly you get the time of day from yourLocalDateTime.toLocalTime().

Use LocalTime instead of LocalDateTime.
